# Setiing Up This Shell Script What Is Wrong With It

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I am writing a script for Kali Linux which will put my network card into monitor mode. But I am running into a issue with the do command in the eighth line when trying to run it. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Preparing to enter monitor mode."`
```

Checks to see if Firefox is running

```
ps cax | grep firefox > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Firefox is running. It needs to be closed in order to properly enter monitor mode." #If it is offers to close it
echo "Would you like me to close it for you?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
case $yn in
Yes ) pkill firefox; echo "Firefox killed. Proceeding to enter monitor mode."; echo "Press any button when ready"; wait;;
No ) echo "Proceeding to enter monitor mode."; echo "Press any button when ready."; wait;;
else
echo "Proceeding to enter monitor mode."
echo "Press any button when ready"
wait
fi
```

Asks name of wireless interface to set variable

```
echo "What is the name of your wireless interface?"
read interfacevar
echo Thank you. Entering $interfacevar into monitor mode.
airmon-ng start $interfacevar
airmon-ng check kill
echo "Complete! Exiting in:"
echo "5"
sleep 1s
echo "4"
sleep 1s
echo "3"
sleep 1s
echo "2"
sleep 1s
echo "1"
sleep 1s
echo "Goodbye!"
exit
```

But I then get issues saying that the do in line 8 isn't correct.

Comment: Use [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) to diagnose your script.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're finishing a `case` block with `else` when you should be finishing it with `esac`

You can fix it by adding a line

```
esac
```

right before the `else`

Comment: Okay I'm not going to lie. I have no clue what that means I basically setup this script by doing a lot of Googling. What precisely would I have to change in the script for it to work?

Comment: You are using a compound command that have a special syntax. You can read about that with `man bash | sed -n '/^\s\{7\}case/,/list\.$/p'`. Or have a look here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html